# PHP Regex replace an entire string that differs a little

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace an entire string in a file.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

I want to do a **preg_replace the entire string**, even the variable. Im having trouble matching it with the RegEx. I have this so far:

```
preg_match("/\$db\['default'\]\['hostname'\]^;");
```

But what Im trying to do is find the entire line and completely replace it with something else. So the Regex would be like:

```
"^$db['default']['hostname'](AnythingHere);$"
```

Does anyone know the character group I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked on RegexPal:

```
(\$db\[\'default']\['hostname'])( = 'localhost')(;)
```

And the replace string should be:

```
\1(AnythingHere)\2
```

[Example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5C%24db%5C%5B%5C%27default%27%5D%5C%5B%27hostname%27%5D%20=%20%27localhost%27;&input=%24db%5B%27default%27%5D%5B%27hostname%27%5D%20=%20%27localhost%27;)

Comment: +1 for a working solution. You could also use non-matching look-ahead patterns for the bits that aren't going to be replaced.